# Will comments slow down the execution time of my webpages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, comments

This might be a pretty strange question in the eyes of some of you out here, but I really wonder if comments in my code will slow down the execution time of the pages I make.
I have some Classes / WebControls that required alot of comments to make everything clear and quickly readable to other people that will have to deal with my code and now wonder how ASP.Net deals with my comments. Will comments be stripped from my code at compile time or how is this all done?

I should be more specific: I mean comments in my code-behind in C#.

Comment: comments in the C# code or in the javascript code or in the HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments serverside in C# won't do anything but a slight increase in compiletime.

Comments in javascript of course increase the downloadsize. But since you usually minify javascript on production systems, and thus strip out the comments and whitespace it doesn't matter in practice.

Since html minification on dynamically generated pages isn't that common, comments in html slow you down a bit, but they typically are so few that it doesn't matter in practice either.

Comment: Just curious.. How can serverside comments cause "slight increase in compiletime"?

Comment: The C# compiler needs to parse them which takes a tiny amount of time.  But unless the amount of comments is excessive the increase won't be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Comments on the aspx pages (like in javascript etc.) are slowing down the page because it is content that needs to be downloaded. For JavaScript you might use a minimizer and have a minimized version of the javascript on the production system.

For c# code... it does not make a difference since the comments are not compiled into the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** Only exception is when you have an exorbitant amount of HTML (`<!--`) comments because this will require extra time to transfer your HTML over the internet. All C# comments will be striped when compiled.

Answer (score 0):

If the comments are in the .aspx page, it will depend on whether they're HTML comments or server-side comments. As Pieter points out, HTML (`!<--`) comments have an impact because they get transferred over the network.

Generally speaking, the more that gets sent to the browser, the longer it will take your pages to load. (It also puts additional load on your server - increased bandwidth usage, and most likely a small increase in CPU load simply because the server has to work harder to send more data.)

That's why ASP.NET supports server-side comments. If you use the `!<%--` ... `--%>` syntax instead, the contents of the comment will not be sent to client. The best way to know for certain what's actually being transferred is to View Source in the browser to see what came across.

Scott Guthrie posted about this back in 2006: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/09/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Using-Server-Side-Comments-with-ASP.NET-2.0-.aspx